# Small memory spike I don't know how to isolate.

Tags: xcode, swift

The app I am making appears to have a memory leak, increasing in about 9mb every 30 minutes of running. The spike happens every 1 minute 30 seconds consistently. It will keep doing this until it eventually crashes.

The app has 2 functions:

- getPrivateIP() which gets the UP internal IP address using ifaddr
- getDns() which uses Alamofire.request to get json DNS information

Here is my code:

```
func getPrivateIp() {

    if (getInternalIp().first != nil) {
    if let ipAdd = getInternalIp().first {
        self.privateIp.title = "Private IP: " + ipAdd
        self.statusItem.title = ipAdd
    }
    } else {
        self.privateIp.title = "No Internet Connection"
        self.statusItem.title = "No Internet Connection"
    }
}

func getDns() {

    Alamofire.request(.GET, dataSourceURL2!)
        .responseJSON { response in

            if (response.result.value != nil) {
            let json2 = JSON(response.result.value!)
            let json3 = json2["dns"]
            let ip = json3["ip"].stringValue

            self.dnsIp.title = "DNS IP: " + ip

            } else {
                self.dnsIp.title = "No Internet Connection"
            }
    }

}
```

I have a timer which calls a method that calls those two methods:

```
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: "refreshIpAddresses", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

I would love if someone could help me debug this issue.